# How can I make an activity scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

Some Buttons in my app are going to set my content View to a layout where is only 1 TextView and a Button. I want that my TextView becomming scroll-able but my button should be fixed, so he stands still on the top or on the buttom. At the moment I have ScrollView (see XMLCode below) but everytime I start it on my Android emulator, my app crashes if I click on the button so my layout with scrollview should show up. Every other layout is working but this one not.

Code doesn't appear correctly, [here's the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPk0W.png).

I've used Linear and Relative layout as well, but I used ConstraintLayout on every layout so there it is as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: can you copy paste your code here in the question? Its annoying to type it in from an imageview

Comment: i'm really sorry but it doesnt work some parts don't appear for some reason, i tried it so long now, i'm so sorry but i guess i can't post it here >.<"

Comment: if u want u can edit my text with "TeamViewer".

Answer (score 0):

just use LinearLayout as root layout then add Button then scrollview then inside it your TextView

**`LinearLayout >> [ Button , ScrollView >> TextView ]`**